# Как поделиться аудиофайлом в Telegram как голосовое сообщение на Android

Tags: android, android-sdk, telegram

Делаю так:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriSound);
sendIntent.setType("audio/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Отправить:"));
```

Отправляется как аудиозапись, а не как голосовое сообщение.
Пробовал копаться в исходном коде Android-клиента telegram, но так ни к чему и не пришел. Понял что судя по `AndroidManifest.xml` в `LaunchActivity.java` разбирается intent, который пришел, и записывается в переменную `documentsPathsArray`.
Возможно telegram определяет тип по какому-то флагу?

Comment: В `whatsapp` есть разница между аудио файлом и голосовым сообщением, а в `Telegram` как вы различаете между этими двумя? Любые аудио файлы в телеграм выглядят одинаково, разве нет?

Comment: @McDaggen нет, иначе не задавал бы вопрос. Прикрепил [скрин](http://s1.radikale.ru/uploads/2018/4/24/5059b411304847846e0122e0c2ee5dab-full.jpg) на котором видно различие: 1-ое – голосовое, 2-ое – аудиозапись.

Comment: В iOS такая возможность есть и не только в `Telegram`, но и в `Whatsapp` и `Facebook`. Интересно, возможно ли это в android?

Comment: @McDaggen с Telegram разобрался, нужно чтобы файлы были в формате .ogg кодека opus. А как отправить в WhatsApp? Ogg кодека opus отправляет как музыку. Записал свой голос через WhatsApp, поделился файлом в формате .opus через файловый менеджер – WhatsApp воспринял это как документ.

Comment: С Whatsapp все сложно в плане поделиться файлами, если я не ошибаюсь, я толком не смог реализовать.

Comment: @McDaggen только через API возможно?

Comment: Почитай в сторону `FileProvider`

Comment: @McDaggen я итак его использую. У меня был вопрос не как поделиться файлом в WhatsApp – с этим все хорошо, а как поделиться аудиофайлом в WhatsApp, чтобы он распознал его как голосовое сообщение?

Comment: Ну наверное тоже самое что и в телеграме, должен быть определенный формат. Если переслать голосовые сообщения из `WhatsApp` они бывают формата `.opus`

Comment: @McDaggen [выше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/817488/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b2-telegram-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-android?noredirect=1#comment1308792_817488) писал про это. WhatsApp воспринимает файлы *.opus как документ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Файлы должны быть формата .ogg кодека opus.